# Can I drive a pulley with two shaded pole motors using one motor at a time with different size pulleys for speed control?

Tags: mechanical-engineering, electrical-engineering, control-engineering, motors, pulleys

Using two same RPM shaded pole motors, one with a one inch diameter motor and one with a two inch diameter. Using a DTDP switch to swap power from one pulley to the other. For a two speed rotation device.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is the principle of the *two speed Leslie speaker* as used with electric organs from the 1950's. two motors mounted on one shaft, two pulleys. select speed by turning one motor off and the other on.